# How does thermal wavelength work exactly?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation, wavelength, quantum-statistics

In many sources it is stated that the thermal wavelenth indicates the rough size of the atom. It is then stated that this wavelenght is the de-Broglie wavelength of a particle with a momentum with the average kinetic energy in that temperature.

I don't really understand what this means in the context of quantum theory. If a particle has a very well defined momentum value, its position is very well undefined. In the limiting case if the particle actually has a de-Broglie wavelength of any value, $\psi$ will be a complex sinusoid with no size at all.

Is the thermal wavelength just an observational fact? Have people just noticed that gas atoms interact with the environment in such a way that the atoms localize to an area which happens to be  the same as the wavelength of a momentum eigenstate with the eigenvalue of expected value of the atoms momentum? Or is there some proof for this somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In many sources it is stated that the thermal wavelenth indicates the rough size of the atom. It is then stated that this wavelenght is the de-Broglie wavelength of a particle with a momentum with the average kinetic energy in that temperature.

Average kinetic energy of an atom is
$$\frac{3}{2}k_B T$$
de-Broglie wave is not an arbitrary wave function $\psi$, but a plane wave with energy
$$ E=\hbar\omega=\frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m},$$
where $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ is the wave vector.
Thus, the definition requires us to equate these quantities:
$$
\frac{3}{2}k_B T = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}
= \frac{h^2}{2m\lambda^2} \Rightarrow \lambda=...$$

**Rough size of atom**
Note that here we treat an atom as a point-like particle, described by a De-Broglie wave. That is, the wave function here is for the overall motion of the atomic center-of-mass, rather than for an inner state of an atom, which is extensively discussed in QM books. This might be a possible source of confusion. Thus, what is meant here by the *size of atom* is not the size of the electronic cloud around the nucleus, but rather the extension of the wave packet in space.

Comment: So in a gas the centre of mass of atoms are described by $\psi$ are plane waves at every situation?

Comment: If this is true, then I have an additional question. I have read that if the thermal $\lambda$ is comparable to intermolecular separation, QM statistics are used because now the particles are indistinquishable, because now they "mix". But if all particles centre of mass $\psi$ are plane waves at any time, whose "size" is the container (completely delocalized), they are completely mixed up all the time. What then really changes when thermal $\lambda$ gets close to the separation?

Comment: @JoelJärnefelt they are not really plane waves - the gas atoms collide and exchange energy and momentum. Thermal wave length is a number that characterizes atoms - it is essentially a rescaled temperature, which may be more convenient to use in some situations.

Comment: That was what I thought so too. So is the assumption in the last chapter of my first question right then? If so, is it an observational fact or is there a proof for this?

Comment: @JoelJärnefelt It's just a definition.